# Run private repository with dind in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-in-docker

I try to run my private docker image along with the **docker-dind** container to be able to run docker commands from the private image in Kubernetes.
My only issue is that the `docker run` command does not read the docker-secrets so fails by requiring to run `docker login`. How could I pass the credentials to the docker run command?

Here the piece of my Kubernetes deployment:

```
  containers:
    - name: docker-private
      image: docker:20.10
      command: ['docker', 'run', '-p', '80:8000', 'private/image:latest' ]
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 10m
          memory: 256Mi
      env:
        - name: DOCKER_HOST
          value: tcp://localhost:2375
      envFrom:
         - secretRef:
             name: docker-secret-keys
    - name: dind-daemon
      image: docker:20.10-dind
      command: ["dockerd", "--host", "tcp://127.0.0.1:2375"]
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 20m
          memory: 512Mi
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
      volumeMounts:
        - name: docker-graph-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker
```

**EDIT**
I do have my certificate as Kubernetes secrets that I try to mount to the running docker but until now without any success :(

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: eyJhXXXXXXdoihfc9w8fwpeojfOFwhfoiuwehfo8wfhoi2ehfioewNlcm5hbWUiOiJlbGRhcmVudGas4hti45ytg45hgiVsZGFXXXXXXyQGVudG9yLmlvIiwiYXV0aCI6IlpXeGtZWEpsYm5SdmNqb3dObVl4WmpjM1lTMDVPRFZrTFRRNU5HRXRZVEUzTXkwMk5UYzBObVF4T0RjeFpUWT0ifX19XXXXXXXXXXX
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: staging-docker-keys
  namespace: staging
  resourceVersion: "6383"
  uid: a7yduyd-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-ae2ede3e4ed
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

The final goal is to get the "inner docker" (that runs private/image:latest) be able to run any docker command without a need to login before each command.

Comment: the docker:dind image is createing a new docker server, how do you get the secret before server created? I am so confuced. where do you get the secret?

Answer (score 4):

docker:dind will create ca, server, client cert in `/certs`.
Just create `emptyDir` volume to share cert.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp
  labels:
    name: myapp
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: docker-tls-certdir
    emptyDir: {}
  containers:
    - name: docker-private
      image: docker:20.10
      command: ['docker', 'run', '-p', '80:8000', 'nginx' ]
      env:
        - name: DOCKER_HOST
          value: tcp://localhost:2375
      volumeMounts:
        - name: docker-tls-certdir
          mountPath: /certs
    - name: dind-daemon
      image: docker:20.10-dind
      command: ["dockerd", "--host", "tcp://127.0.0.1:2375"]
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
      volumeMounts:
        - name: docker-tls-certdir
          mountPath: /certs
```

Comment: I modify the pod yaml file to mount the `/certs` folder but I still get an access denied.
---------------------------------------------
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for entor/docker-runner-api, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

Comment: I tested the yaml, it can use docker command without any modify. Just copy and paste it.

Comment: Yes, of course it works fine. The nginx image is public so no need for authentication. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are not using [docker cert authentication](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/), but username and password you may follow the below path:

- modify docker client image (`docker:20.1`) entrypoint using `command` field
- `command` may look like below:

```
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "docker login...;docker run..."]
```

Sample working pod using the idea:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp
  labels:
    name: myapp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapp
    image: docker:20.10
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "docker version;docker info"]  
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "500m"
```

Based on [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#running-a-command-in-a-shell)

EDIT:

If you do use docker cert authentication, you can have many options:

- bake the certificates by extending `docker` client image and using it instead.
- mount the certificates if you have them as Kubernetes secrets in the cluster
  ...

Comment: Yes, this would work great! 
Although, I think it would be safer to use the certificated to access the docker images.

Comment: Thanks for the precision!
Yes I do have my certificate as Kubernetes secrets that I try to mount to the running docker but until now without any success :(

Comment: apiVersion: v1
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: eyJdlqndkabsdkjabsdkabdkasndkasnbdknbasdkband,bacb askcbnasldhalsdnlasdnlandlandlandandlandlandlandljeijueou23oerh2ofh2ohfo2hfo2hfo2hfdo2qhfoh2foih2
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: staging-docker-keys
  namespace: staging
  resourceVersion: "6383"
  uid: a8ad8sad8d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-aa6a6s6asd6d6
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally created [an access token](https://docker-docs.netlify.app/ee/dtr/user/access-tokens/#create-an-access-token) on my docker repository and used it to perform the `docker login` command. It works just fine :)